# adding an array to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html

i am a newbie to HTML5.
I am reading **head first HTML5 programming.**
Here in a chapter it's mentioned that We are grabbing the array out of `localStorage`.

```
function init() {
    // button code here...
    var stickiesArray = localStorage["stickiesArray"];
    if (!stickiesArray) {
        stickiesArray = [];
        localStorage.setItem("stickiesArray", stickiesArray);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < stickiesArray.length; i++) {
        var key = stickiesArray[i];
        var value = localStorage[key];
        addStickyToDOM(value);
    }
}
```

I didn't understand this line
**`var stickiesArray = localStorage["stickiesArray"];`**

We are grabbing StickiesArray out of Localstorage.
But should not there be a dot between them like
   **`var stickiesArray = localStorage.stickiesArray;`**
to grab the items from localstorage??
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: It's the same thing. In javascript you can use either bracket notation or dot notation to access objects.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to access a property in an object, dot and bracket notation.

Dot Notation: `myObject.property`

Bracket Notation: `myObject["property"]`

At runtime dot notation is actually converted to bracket notation, it's just a shorthand for us programmers.  This means that anything using dot notation is going to be converted to a string.  So if you're in a for-in loop like so:

```
for(var key in object) {
  // object.key -> object["key"] (This will be undefined)
  object[key] // (looks up the variable 'key')
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the bracket notation is the only way to access a property where the name is contained in a variable (e.g., `myObject[prop]` is the value in `myObject` of the property name currently stored in `prop`). Of course, for `localStorage` there's yet another way: `localStorage.getItem("property")`.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, when you have object literal notation...aka declaring objects outright, and/or declaring key/value pairs, you have two choices:

`Object.name = "FOO";`
or 
`Object['name'] = "FOO";`

dot notation may often be preferred for ease of use, but brackets have a larger scope in that they can ALWAYS be used.  There are instances in object literals where dot notation is not allowed.

`var stickiesArray = localStorage["stickiesArray"]`
sets the variable stickiesArray equal to an object that has a property/value of local storage: stickiesArray.